# static или не static

Tags: c#

Программ-привет!:)
У меня возник такой вопрос: когда предпочтительнее создавать статичные функции, а когда нет? Например, в случае когда функция использует нестатичные поля класса, лучше сделать ее статичной и все нужные парметры передавать, или же оставить ее нестатичной, и тогда ничего ей передавать не надо, а просто обращаться к полям класса?

Comment: "Нестатичные поля класса" -- это вроде поля экземпляра класса. Если работать с ними, то лучше метод не объявлять static. А если нужны функции в традиционном смысле этого слова (например математические: синус, косинус) -- тогда static. Ибо понятие функции самой по себе уже заменено на статический метод класса (что поначалу и кажется странным)

Comment: > что поначалу и кажется странным

рассматривайте это просто как пространство имен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Примитивное объяснение**

Статичные функции следует использовать тогда, когда не требуется создавать экземпляр класса. Это, например, вспомогательный класс. Если же объект создается, то есть используется оператор new:

```
 SomeClass element = new SomeClass();
```

мне кажется в этом примере не имеет смысла создание static - метода.

**Для продвинутых**

Читать надо эту статью: [Семь советов по применению статических полей, методов и классов](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd335949.aspx)

> А это заключение из вышеуказанной
> статьи:
>
> При добавлении статических членов в
> тип нужно оценить, к чему это приведет
> в период разработки и в период
> выполнения. При разработке необходимо
> тщательно выбирать, какие члены будут
> статическими, и стремиться сохранить
> объектно-ориентированную архитектуру.
> Постарайтесь не смешивать в одном
> классе разнородную функциональность:
> класс не должен быть свалкой не
> связанных друг с другом статических
> методов. Если класс содержит только
> статические члены, не забудьте
> пометить класс как статический или
> запечатанный (sealed/NotInheritable) и
> определить закрытый конструктор
> класса, чтобы сделать невозможным
> создание экземпляра.
>
> Кроме того, помните, что статические
> классы, сохраняющие состояние между
> вызовами методов, по умолчанию должны
> быть безопасными в многопоточной
> среде. Когда вы разрабатываете класс,
> безопасный в многопоточной среде,
> нужна особая аккуратность при
> реализации и тестировании класса.
> Прежде чем приступить к созданию
> такого класса, спросите себя,
> действительно ли эти дополнительные
> издержки абсолютно необходимы.
>
> Безопасность в многопоточной среде
> влияет на производительность
> приложения. В этой статье вы видели,
> как может уменьшиться
> производительность из-за того, что у
> класса есть статический конструктор.
> Оценить влияние на производительность
> особенно важно, если вы пишете
> библиотеку, предназначенную для
> многократного использования. Никогда
> заранее не известно, будет ли кто-то
> применять ваш класс в самом худшем
> случае, подобном описанному в начале
> статьи.
>
> Наконец, старайтесь тщательно
> документировать свои статические
> классы. Обычно вполне понятно, когда
> статическим методам присваивают имена
> типичных операций, как в случае
> статических методов Open и Copy класса
> System.IO.FileClass. Если вы
> реализуете нетривиальный класс,
> сохраняющий состояние между вызовами
> методов, пользователей класса будут
> интересовать детали, связанные с
> производительностью и безопасностью в
> многопоточной среде. Чем больше
> информации о классе вы предоставите
> заранее, тем меньше времени на
> устранение неполадок потратите в
> дальнейшем.*

Comment: Очень примитивное объяснение.

Comment: А если у меня функция не использует никаких нестатичных внутренних полей, а все данные получает в параметрах, то, помоему, логичнее было бы сделать ее статичной. Или я не прав?

Comment: Хотя бы из соображений "нафига создавать ненужный экземпляр класса для вызова этой функции"?

Comment: @Данил, статические функции в C# это некоторый аналог чистых функций, т.е. функций без побочных эффектов, которые зависят только от передаваемых параметров(при одинаковых параметрах всегда получаете одиниковый результат), следовательно вы правы

Comment: Дак и все-таки, к чему стоит стремится? По возможности делать статические?

Comment: Делая функции по возможности статическими, вы скатываетесь к процедурному программированию и не сможете применять ООП в ОО языке - типичная ошибка новичков.

Comment: далать функцию, которая не зависит от состояния объекта экземплярной как минимум глупо, почему в C# методы консоли и ковертера статические? потому что они зависят только от передаваемых параметров(ещё потому что экземпляр консоли и конвертера всего один), если у вас схожая ситуация делайте стотик!

Comment: Мои комментарий говорит о том, что делать "по возможности все методы статическими" в корень глупо! И я видел массу примеров, когда в классе члены делают также статическими для использования в статических методах. Разумеется статика нужна и важна, но злоупотреблять ей нельзя! Что касается консоли и конвертера, то это статические классы (по упомянутым причинам) и не могут иметь экземплярных членов.

Comment: Ну статические члены -- это замена глобальных переменных, которые есть в других языках.

Answer (score 0):

Статичные функции используются для удобства, по сути они заменяют конструкцию:

MyClass MyVar = new MyClass();

MyVar.DoSmth();

на

MyClass.DoSmth();

что в ряде случаев короче.

Для C# со сборщиком мусора это не так актуально, так как конструкция не очень громоздкая получается, а вот на Delphi, например, выигрыш в плане объёма кода куда больше.

С точки зрения производительности статические методы также как правило предпочтительней, но не стоит гоняться за производительностью в ущерб понятности и читабельности кода.